# Countifs Array Formula

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, countif

I am trying to use a `countifs` array formula to obtain how many cells in a column start with `"EU_w"` and `"W_"`, if the corresponding cell in a different column has a certain value.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(QC_Data!C:C,{"EU_w*","W_*"}, QC_Data!M:M,A4))
```

I am receiving `"0"`, which is incorrect. I searched other questions, but I had no luck. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to look at your data and make sure there are not extra spaces or other non printable characters that would cause excel to not see them as equal.  There is nothing wrong with the formula, at least from what I see.

Comment: Perhaps it is also worth clarifying that the formula posted is not an 'array formula' in the sense of requiring CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to commit (it doesn't). It does operate over an array of values, however, so your title and question are not misleading.